# Not duplicate values ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm entering data in the database, but when the value of the slug and the site is duplicated it must update. But I can not succeed every time it adds a new line with the repeated data.

```
mysql;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default   | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+
| id_tag     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | None      |       | 
| nome_tag   | varchar(200) | NO   |     | None      |       | 
| slug_tag   | varchar(200) | NO   |     | None      |       | 
| usuario_tag| int(3)       | NO   |     | None      |       |      
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------+-------+

DATA;
+------------+--------------+---------+------------+
| id_tag     | nome_tag     | slug_tag| usuario_tag|
+------------+--------------+---------+------------+
| 1          | Maria        | maria   | 1          |
| 2          | Car          | car     | 1          |
| 3          | Musa         | musa    | 1          |
| 4          | Tota         | tota    | 1          |   
| 5          | Maria        | maria   | 1          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+


$vai = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tab_tags (nome_tag, slug_tag, usuario_tag) VALUES('$nome_tag', '$slug_tag', $usuario_tag) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE slug_tag = '$slug_tag'");
$vai->execute();
var_dump($vai->queryString);

 string 'INSERT INTO tags (nome_tag, slug_tag,  usuario_tag) VALUES('Maria', 'maria', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE slug_tag = 'maria'' (length=148)
```

How do I duplicate it does not, I would like to do an Update, but he always doubles the data.

Comment: What are the indexes on your table? Which columns are unique?

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY does exactly that, it checks to see if the KEY is duplicate, not other columns. Your Key is id_tag, not slug_tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `UNIQUE` index on columns `nome_tag` and `slug_tag`:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_tags ADD UNIQUE INDEX `nome_slug` (`nome_tag`, `slug_tag`)
```